# After updating MvvmCross 5.2 I have error Fragment already active

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a problem after updating to the new MvvmCross `5.2`.

I have forced uninstalled `MvvmCross.Droid.Shared` and after update all packages. I then got some errors with `MvxFragment`, so I replaced it with `MvxFragmentPresentation`. Additionally, I replaced `MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity` with `MvxAppCompatActivity` and I'm now using the new `MvxAppCompatViewPresenter`. All works well, and the app running good. Except after I select logout in menu I'm taken to the `LoginViewModel` and when I want Login again I get this error

> Fragment already active.

Can someone help me?

My test project is [HERE](https://github.com/pinkysek/XabluDemoApp) on github.

**It fail here, by the `ShowViewModel`**

```
   public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public void ShowMenu()
        {
            ShowViewModel<MenuViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are mixing your methods for presenting in MvvmCross. With MvvmCross `5.x` a new prefer way to navigate was introduced using the [`IMvxNavigationService`](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation). For new apps it is suggested that you rather make use of the `IMvxNavigationService` over the prior `ShowViewModel`. It is advised that you do not mix the use of the two different ways to navigate as you may get some strange behaviour.

Switching to that `IMvxNavigationService` which you are already using on the `LoginViewModel` will solve the exception you are getting.

```
protected readonly IMvxNavigationService _mvxNavigationService;

public MainViewModel(IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService)
{
    _mvxNavigationService = mvxNavigationService;
}

public void ShowMenu()
{
    _mvxNavigationService.Navigate<MenuViewModel>();
}
```

Additionally, you will want to remove adding `HomeFragment` to the backstack to prevent seeing a white page when navigation back.

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
public class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<HomeViewModel>
```

See [pull request](https://github.com/pinkysek/XabluDemoApp/pull/1) for full details of changes.

---

**Additional notes**

Rather than explicitly specifying `MvxAppCompatViewPresenter` in your `Setup` which inherits `MvxAndroidSetup` you can rather inherit from [`MvxAppCompatSetup`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat/MvxAppCompatSetup.cs#L14) which will automatically make use of the `MvxAppCompatViewPresenter` as well as register additional `AndroidViewAssemblies` relating to support libraries (see link to which assemblies) and `FillTargetFactories` for the `MvxAppCompatSetupHelper`.